# Client-Server architecture behind chat applications using socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am learning socket programming using `socket.io` module. I couldn't understand the client-server architecture behind the application programmed using socket. 
For example, A is chatting with B using a chat application, both A and B are hosts similar to peer-to-peer architecture. 
Where does the server come into this picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A will be connected P2P to the server.
B will be connected P2P to the server.

So when A send a message, the server print it out to all other client (B in this context). Exacly the same for B.

A and B arn't connected each other. But you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

there is no peer-to-peer connections with `socket.io`.
all the communications are managed server-side and you can have different namespaces and rooms. for more info look [here](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/).

there are different transport protocol that you can use, such as HTTP or [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

if you want to scale up the machines using a load balancer be aware that you have to implement a  [sticky session](https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) load balancing. for example you can use the `ip_hash` option of nginx.